# Python split and subsequent join on os.sep does not yield properly joint string

Tags: python, string, path

python 3.8 on Windows 10

I'm trying to create a script to automatically create a .bat file to activate the correct environment or the current script. For this I need to do some path manipulation, which includes in essence the following code:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
s = cwd.split(os.sep)
n = os.path.join(*s,'test.bat')
print(n)
```

Expected outcome:

```
C:\\Data\\test.bat
```

Actual outcome:

```
C:Data\\test.bat
```

This is missing the \ separator after the drive.
Also with deeper folder structures, this goes wrong only in joining the drive. What is going wrong here?

Full code:

```
import os

python_file = 'python_file_name.py'  # file to run
program_name = 'Start Python Program'  # Name of the resulting BAT file

cwd = os.getcwd()  # directory in which the Python file lives
env = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']  # environment name in Conda
act = os.environ['CONDA_EXE'].split(os.sep)[:-1]  # activate.bat lives in the same directory as conda.exe
act = os.path.join(*act,'activate.bat')

# Construct the commands

text = f'''ECHO ON
CD {cwd}
CALL {act} {env}
CALL {python_file}
'''

with open(f'{program_name}.bat', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: Don't think you need to split, just `os.path.join(cwd, 'test.bat')` should work?

Comment: I only showed the simplified code for easy understanding. I just included the full code.

Comment: This is a work-around, but doesn't answer the question: `(os.sep).join([*s]+['test.bat'])`

Comment: Still no answer, but I found out more: it fails ONLY on the first item in the split list (I can insert ":" anywhere else and it works) and ONLY on single-letter drives. It doesn't matter whether or not such a drive exists in my system, but it refuses to properly join things like C:, D:, Y:, Z: in the first position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough this seems to be a feature, not a bug...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html